# recordset close when updatesql?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, adodb

I have an Excel VBA to update data in Access. I use the script below.
I just have a small question. if I close the recordset with rs.close I get the message 'operation is not allowed when the object is closed'. If I do not use the rs.close then it works perfectly.

- Is the rs.close really necessary when using a sql?
- I also tried to use cn.execute updatesql. How to set the recordlocking property?

  ```
     Public Sub Upload_to_DB()
        Call setparameters
         ' exports data from the worksheet to a table in an Access database
        Dim cn As ADODB.Connection ws As Worksheet , updatesql As String, r_fld As Long, r_val As Long, c As Long, str As String, rs As ADODB.Recordset




        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        cn.mode = 16 + 3
        cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
        "Data Source= " & Path & filename & ";"
        cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

        Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        Set ws = Sheets("Opportunity_down_and_upload")


      With ws  
    r_fld = 13     
    r_val = 14     
    c = 3

    str = Empty

    str = .Cells(r_fld, c).Offset(0, -1).Value & " = " & .Cells(r_val, c).Offset(0, -1).Value

    continue = True
         Do
        str = str & " , " & .Cells(r_fld, c).Value & " = " & .Cells(r_val, c).Value
        c = c + 1
                If IsEmpty(.Cells(r_fld, c)) Then continue = False
        Loop Until continue = False
             End With

   'This part is important:'

    updatesql = "UPDATE tbl_D_opp_prod_offer SET "
    updatesql = updatesql & str
    updatesql = updatesql & " WHERE [Opp_ID] =  " & ws.Range("A10") & ";"

    rs.Open updatesql, cn, , adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    cn.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

    End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is the rs.close really necessary when using a sql?

  Nope. In fact, `rs.close` is rarely necessary at all. VBA will automatically remove objects when they go out of scope, which means that if they were defined in a sub, they get removed at the end of it. For ADODB, there were some bugs in an old version causing this to be unreliable, which means old code often contains `rs.close` or `connection.close` while they're not really necessary
- I also tried to use cn.execute updatesql. How to set the recordlocking property?

  You can't. It doesn't really apply to action queries. The record locking options define if a record should be locked when starting to edit it, when updating it, or can't be locked at all because it's read-only, and since you're using an update query there's no time in between those

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will not really worry about rs.close then.